# How to map Request parameter in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using spring MVC. When user have registered, an email will be send to User Account.

That is working fine .. and i'm also sending user id encrypted to User email and for that i wrote a template ..

```
<bean id="activateAccountTemplate" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
    <property name="subject" value="Account activation" />
    <property name="text">
        <value>
        <![CDATA[
            <html><body><p>Dear %s</p><p>Click <a href="http://localhost:8080/EClass/home?a=%s">here</a> to activate your account.</p></body></html>
        ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When ever User get email and click to activate... Url coming like this..

```
http://localhost:8080/EClass/home?a=tdpTA3Dz8DYSI+9F/DpMxmxGD/a1Kl+3oYqXc1NNH0U=
```

And i want to get this encrypted userid and for this i'm writing method..

```
    @Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="home", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model model) throws Exception {
        model.addAttribute(FormType.LOGIN.name(), FormType.LOGIN.getNewInstance());
        model.addAttribute(FormType.SIGNUP.name(), FormType.SIGNUP.getNewInstance());
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="active", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String active(@RequestParam("a") String activeCode) throws Exception {

        String userid = CryptUtil.decrypt(activeCode);
        System.out.println("User id Displayed ===="+userid);
        return "home";
    }   
}
```

But nothing happen on server console...
Basically i want to get userid and using userid update User column `Activate=Yes`..

Please suggest me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `http://localhost:8080/EClass/home` will basically call your controller method with a as the parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model model) throws Exception {
}
```

But basically from your question you want to call

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/active", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String active(@RequestParam("a") String activeCode) throws Exception {
}
```

So change your request as

```
<html><body><p>Dear %s</p><p>Click <a href="http://localhost:8080/EClass/active?a=%s">here</a>
```

also specify a `/` in the value attribute of request mapping.

Comment: Exception coming:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'LOGIN' available as request attribute
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)

Comment: @NarasimhamK you are trying to use the Login attribute in your JSP withoout setting it in the controller class the login attribute is set in the home () method and not in active() method so change your code accordingly .

Comment: @NarasimhamK in your  public String home() method you are setting   model.addAttribute(FormType.LOGIN.name(), FormType.LOGIN.getNewInstance()); so i amssuming your are trying to use that attribute somewhere in your JSP but now that you have changed your request mapping to action that method does not contain this attribute but i think your still trying to access it in JSP.

Comment: @Lakshmi.. Thankyou for your reply... Problem solved.. i'm forgot the slash(/) at return statement ..i.e., return "/home"

Answer (score 1):

You need to map your RequestMapping to "home":

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: the URL http://localhost:8080/EClass/home?a=tdpTA3Dz8DYSI+9F/DpMxmxGD/a1Kl+3oYqXc1NNH0U= will call the method with RequestMapping(value="/home"). The param **a=xxxx** will be caught by @RequestParam("a") String activeCode. So either change the RequestMapping, or the URL (to http://localhost:8080/EClass/active?a=%s)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a slash `/` in your request mapping. Add `/` at the controller class level **or** at the method level. But not both..