# How to set action attribute dynamically to Hyperlink?

Tags: java, spring, hyperlink, jakarta-mail

In my Spring Sample Application have their in Register option, User simple enter his email Address and sending mail to that email Address.

All are working Perfectly, But the problem is When user getting some activation mail

But i want When he click that mail (hyper link) following method will call

```
@RequestMapping(value = "activate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String activate(SignUp form,BindingResult result,Model model) {

    --------(hear some database code)
}
```

And this is Activation mail generation code.

```
    <bean id="activateAccountTemplate" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">

    <property name="text">
        <value>
        <![CDATA[
            <html><body><p>Dear %s</p><p>Click <a href="http://localhost:8080/SpringDemo5?a=%s">here</a> to activate your account.</p></body></html>
        ]]>
        </value>
    </property>

</bean>
```

and User getting this message.

```
 Dear Ram

Click here to activate your account.
```

So how to assign that request mapping to hyperlink?

Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to map URLs to Java methods in your code?
You could use a SimpleUrlHandlerMapping, like in these two examples :

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-simpleurlhandlermapping-example/

http://www.raistudies.com/spring/spring-mvc/simpleurlhandlermapping/

Comment: also check out this related Stack Overflow question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564906/how-to-map-request-parameter-in-spring?rq=1